# Resize main layout content to fit Bottom Sheet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to create a layout with a persistent bottom sheet and a NestedScrollView providing the main content. Unfortunately, when the Bottom Sheet is expanded, it obscures the NestedScrollView and it's bottom items cannot be accessed. ?

What's the best approach for resizing the main NestedScroll to fit the expanded Bottom Sheet?

As an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- I want this view resized dependent on bottom sheet expansion -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       <!-- content goes here -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottomsheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <!-- bottom sheet content goes here -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to obtain what you need avoiding to obscure the view behind the Bottom Sheet and handle its touches.

You need to extend a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

```
public class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }
```

In onStart() you can remove the background dim so that you can have your behind view clear.

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View rootView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_bottom_sheet_layout, null);
    dialog.setContentView(rootView);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    // set your children views

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            // Do stuff when the dialog is visible on screen
            Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
            if(window != null) {
                window.setCallback(windowCallback);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In setupDialog() inflate your layout and avoid to dismiss the dialog with any touch outside that you can handle by setting a window callback like the following one:

```
private Window.Callback windowCallback = new Window.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return onDispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreatePanelView(int featureId) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowAttributesChanged(WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested(SearchEvent searchEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback, int type) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

    }
};
```

By setting this callback you need to manage every single touch. It's a bit tricky but you can obtain target.
The onDispatchTouchEvent(event) has to be something like this:

```
@Override
protected boolean onDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // check if the dialog is being touched
    float eventX = event.getRawX();
    float eventY = event.getRawY();
    int location[] = new int[2];
    yourDialogRootView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    boolean isDialogBeingTouched = eventX > (location[0] - leftPaddingX)
            && eventX < (location[0] + view.getWidth())
            && eventY > (location[1])
            && eventY < (location[1] + view.getHeight());

    if (isDialogBeingTouched) {
        checkForAClick(event);
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (isDialogBeingTouched) {
                // the dialog is touched so handle its touch
                return true;
            }
    }

    // dialog not touched so let the activity handle the touch normally
    return getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The checkForAClick(event) should be something like this:

```
protected boolean checkForAClick(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float endX = event.getX();
            float endY = event.getY();
            if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) {
                // handle click on your dialog as you prefer
                onBottomSheetClick(event);
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

private static int CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD = 50;

public boolean isAClick(float startX, float endX, float startY, float endY) {
    float differenceX = Math.abs(startX - endX);
    float differenceY = Math.abs(startY - endY);
    if (differenceX > CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD || differenceY > CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I know it's a bit long explanation but I hope it can help.